# Umbraco - formatAsDateWithTimeSeperator not working

Tags: umbraco, umbraco6

**Documentation is [here](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Templating/Masterpages/umbracoitem)**

In the Umbraco master template, I have this:

`<div><umbraco:Item runat="server" Field="date" formatAsDateWithTime="true" formatAsDateWithTimeSeperator="sep"></umbraco:Item></div>`

which takes the field of the content page with the alias of `date` and return it as a string formatted as a date with time, with `sep` being the separator.

It should insert `sep` between the date and the time. But it is coming back as:

`Sunday, April 13, 20142:18 PM`

It should be:

`Sunday, April 13, 2014sep2:18 PM`

**Why is it not working?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a typo in the documentation, separator is spelt incorrectly. The correct name is

```
formatAsDateWithTimeSeparator
```

Comment: I have made a pull request to fix the typo in the documentation also.